# CommunicationException in EF if entity is in a relation

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, entity-framework, service

I have two tables in my database (for the sake of this example).
Products and Images. They are in a one to many relationship. The relationship is done with a foreign key in the database
I genereated an EF .edmx file based on the database and all is well.
My one and only problem is that this .edmx is in a WCF project and if I return a Product object I get the following exception in the client:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://gdatasynchservice.asphostpage.net/SynchService/DataSynchService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'

If I delete the relationship everything is fine with the WCF service, except the .edmx doesnt let me NOT map the relationship, because there's an FK key constraint in the DB which has to be mapped. If I delete that everything works, but I'd rather not go around and delete every FK key in the DB, because then I'd be back with LINQ-TO-SQL which is way worse then the EF.

I suppose I'm doing something very stupid. Please advise.

(My code not sure if you'll be needing it, I don't think this has anything to do with VB.NET)

```
Function GetProductById(username As String, pass As String, productid As Integer) 
    As Product Implements SynchService.GetProductById
    If ValidateLogin(username, pass) Then
        Using db As New GaranciaEntities
            Try
                Dim prod = db.Products.Where(Function(n) n.ProductID = productid)
                             .First
                Return prod
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

client side:

`Dim db As New ServiceReference1.SynchServiceClient
        Dim prod= db.GetProductById("", "", 40)`

Comment: your data contract may not be completely serializable. did you try debugging the service?

Comment: how could i find out if it is fully serializable?

Comment: Don't return the whole classes from EF model. Create some Data Transfer Objects (DTO) and return only what you need.